How to Get value from local.setting.json
I have below in local.settings.json
{
    "Values": {
        "Name": "test"
    },
    "Connectionstring": {
        "Myconnection": "myconnectionstring"
    }
}

I want to get value from connectionstring , I need help to get value from it.
I tried with config.getsection()
And getConfigSection(),
Also tried with Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("")
All above is returning null response

Can you provide the code where you want to use these values ? you want to use these values inside the function? and what is the trigger you are using

I want to get value in business layer

I dont see any array in that json.

Provide the code, where you want and the rest of code

You might (also) be interested in the Options pattern in .Net.


I want to get value from connectionstring , I need help to get value
from it.
I tried with config.getsection() And getConfigSection(),
Also tried with Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("")
All above is returning null response

Based on your scenario and description, in order to extact connectionstring key and value which is "Myconnection": "myconnectionstring" you could extract it using couple of ways. For example, it can be retrieved from program.cs file and controller level as well.
Let's have a look in practice how we can get it on either environment.
Program.cs:
Way:1
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var connectionStringValue = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Connectionstring:Myconnection");


Way:2
  var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("local.setting.json").Build();
var way_2_getConnectionString = configuration.GetValue<string>("Connectionstring:Myconnection");


Controller Level:
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _appSettingsValue;
        private string ConnectionStringValue;
    
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _appSettingsValue = configuration;
            ConnectionStringValue = _appSettingsValue["Connectionstring:Myconnection"]!;
        }
    
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
           
            var getAppSettingsValue = ConnectionStringValue;
            return View();
        }
    }

Output:

Read Array:
In addition, if you want to read key-value pairs as following:
"keys": [
  {
    "keyName1": "example1"
  },
  {
    "keyName2": "example2"
  }
],

In above scenario, you can extract the value like below:
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("YourFileName.json").Build();
           
            var keyName1 = configuration.GetValue<string>("keys:0:keyName1");
            var keyName2 = configuration.GetValue<string>("keys:1:keyName2");

Note: You can refer to this sample. If you would like to know more details on configuration providers you could check our official document here

The connection string structure for the local.settings.json is
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Myconnection": "myconnectionstring"
}

You have typo in the key, it's not Connectionstring. Fix it and you can access it from environment variables
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStrings:Myconnection");

The second way is, if you are good with not static class for your function, you can use DI.
Use injected dependencies
Then you can pass IConfiguration to the constructor
public Function1(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    this.configuration = configuration;
}

And you can use it as normally from your function
configuration.GetConnectionString("Myconnection")

or
configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetValue<string>("Myconnection")


You should be storing connection strings in a section named "ConnectionStrings", not "Connectionstring". I have this code in a Startup class:
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(builder.GetContext().ApplicationRootPath)
                                              .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", true, true)
                                              .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                                              .Build();
// ...
var eotrConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("EyeOnTheReefConnection");

That will get the connection string from the JSON file in dev and from Azure after deployment.
If you want to get settings from a named section then you can use this:
configuration.GetSection("SectionName").Bind(ClassName.PropertyName);

where ClassName.PropertyName is a static property of a type that has properties that correspond to the value names in your section.
